# Browser fonts have changed on mac and will not change back

Tags: fonts, default, chromium

Please help me. I have tried changing the font from Chromium & Brave's settings page but nothing is fixing this. I have scoured Google's search results but as you can imagine searching for "Changing browser font" delivers millions of results and none have been specific to this issue.

Attached is the misery I am experiencing. My granddaughter grabbed my macbook pro and I don't know what she did in her 40 seconds or how to fix it. Also attached is my attempt to fix within browser settings but with zero change.

Please help.
 [image: Complete Hell]

[image: Chromium Settings]

Comment: verify that she didn't just install a normal web extension ("add on") that replaces fonts with this fantasy font first. And also: did you ask her what she did? Because asking others to guess when you have access to the actual source means you forgot the most important first step.

Comment: I wish she could, but she is only 2 years old. I do not have any  extensions that look like they could do this in Google Chrome, and have zero installed in the Brave browser. It is odd that Both browsers are doing this. Safari is not. I did disable the few add ons and extensions that I did have, still showing this horrid font.

Meanwhile I will use that trick in reverse while hoping to find a solution. Thanks Mike.

Comment: might also be worth asking in https://superuser.com/ as this isn't specifically programming related - it sounds more like a general "what the heck happened to my mac" question.